# facebook accountkit android error on specific device

Tags: android, facebook, account-kit

I using facebook account kit, but not work on specific device ( Asus Zenfone 3 max, OS Nouget).

is there any issue compability with specific device? or my code is wrong?

FYI, i am using :

> compile 'com.facebook.android:account-kit-sdk:4.23.0'
>
> compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.20.0'
>
> compile 'com.facebook.shimmer:shimmer:0.1.0@aar'
>
> compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:$playServiceVersion"
>
> compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:$playServiceVersion"
>
> compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:$playServiceVersion"
>
> compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:$playServiceVersion"
>
> compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:$playServiceVersion"
>
> compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:$playServiceVersion"

is there anyone get problem same with me?

this is screen result error :
[error result when i try account kit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pdtHV.png)
in my android studio there's no error shown

Comment: Are you getting any error? or what problem you are facing?

Comment: got error 
android.permission.READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE is denied. and the result is likes i put above. what the causes for this?

Comment: That the app was denied permission to read the privileged phone status ... as it says?

Comment: yes, this only happen to device asus with OS Marshmallow, and Nougat. on other device this not happen. i don't know why

Comment: can you share more details/snippet on the error logs u r getting & the manifest. Are u requesting READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE? As its a Privilege Permission it can't be accessed by any other than system apps, thus to help you better can you please share more details on what your trying to do/achieve ? And also which other phones/OS version u checked that it works fine?